# What is reliable way to dispatch action for dynamic components?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say that I have state with elements that represent different data types of objects. 
Each element can have a different action to dispatch

```
export default connect(
    (state) => {
      return {
          events: getRegisteredEventsList(state).map(item => {
            return {
              title: item.get('name'),
              actionButton: <a onClick={dispatch(someActionForThisSpecifiedItem(item))}>Custom Action</a>
            }
          })
    },
    (dispatch) => {
      return {

      }
    }
)(Dashboard)
```

What is reliable way to achieve this kind of pattern ? 
Should I put `dispatch` method to my container's props?

How do I achieve that at this point is:

```
export default connect(
    (state) => {
      return {
          events: getRegisteredEventsList(state).map(item => {
            return {
              title: item.get('name'),
              actionButton: ({dispatch}) => <a
                  className={"btn btn-success"}
                  onClick={() => dispatch(someActionForThisSpecifiedItem(item))}>Go To</a>
            }
          })
    }
)(Dashboard)
```

adding method:

```
  renderActionButtons() {
    const { actionButtons, dispatch } = this.props
    return actionButtons.map(button => renderComponent(button, {
      dispatch
    }));
  }
```

into my dummy component  - which is violation of separation of concerns because my view components now need to know and maintain dispatch property

I feel like that could be redux a feature request as well.

Comment: Not sure if i understand what you're trying to do exactly, do you have a list of items and would like to create a link for each one, each dispatching a different action?

Comment: Yes. Same time someone told me that I should not add components definition in mapStateToProps. But I need it when metadata of specific item is different I want to render different component. Think that is good place here instead of switch in Dashboard component.

Comment: in this case this can also be done, please refer to my updated answer to view one way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this, lets say for simplicity your state is something like this:

```
const items = [{
  name: 'abc',
}, {
  name: 'def',
}];
```

The link component which simply dispatches an action when it's clicked

```
const Link = ({name, onClick}) => <a onClick={() => onClick(name)}>{name}</a>;
```

The render links component which accepts the following props: a list of items and the onClick function which is capable of dispatching actions

```
const RenderLinks = ({ items, onClick }) => (
  <div>
    {items.map(a =>
      <Link
        name={a.name}
        onClick={onClick}
      />)}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  items,
});
```

The onClick function has the ability to dispatch the actions

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onClick: (name) => dispatch({type: `${name.toUpperCase()}_CLICKED`}),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RenderLinks);
```

Comment: Makes sense! Exposing onActionButtonClick it's better than dispatch from my understanding. @enzoborgfrantz let me ask you about one more think. What do you think about adding React component definition in mapStateToProps. It's about rendering different component for each element. I'd rather do that than switch for specific type in Dashboard component

Comment: In my opinion the mapStateToProps function should be used for mapping state data to component props. If you would like to go in that direction I would instead look into higher order components, which are basically components which take other components as a parameter and return a new component with added functionality for example you can create a higher order component: buttonWithClick which takes a button component as a parameter, and wraps it with the click functionality, returning a new button component with click functionality

Comment: check this out for further reading: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html